# Replacing new lines with semi colons in String from RichTextBox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox in which a user will input product barcodes into seperated onto new lines.

I want to then get the text and pass it to a string but replace the new lines with semicolons to separate them.

```
 Dim products As String = txt_distributorProducts.Text
```

Can I use the `.Replace()` method and replace "\n" with ";"? Or will this not work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: My idea was correct however, I needed to use ControlChars.Lf rather than "\n"

Comment: Yeh you can it's usable.

Comment: Yeah, "\n" has no special meaning in VB because VB doesn't support the backslash as an escape character.  That would have worked in C#.

Comment: String.Join(";", txt_distributorProducts.Lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichTextBox has a [Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns an array of all the lines in the control. Simply join the array with your desired glue:

```
Dim products As String = String.Join(";", txt_distributorProducts.Lines)
```

Also for what it's worth, you cannot use escaped Strings in Visual Basic .NET like you can in C#. The `\n` equivalent in Visual Basic is `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: It is not equivalent, matters for RTB which is oddball since it uses \n instead of \r\n as a line separator.  VB.NET has vbLf as a convenience const.

Comment: @HansPassant generally speaking, Environment.NewLine is the correct equivalent. But you're correct in that the LineFeed character is needed for the RTB. However, I would disagree in using anything that exposes the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace and instead use the .NET equivalent of `Convert.ToChar(10)`.

Comment: Hmm, it is not wrong use Microsoft.VisualBasic in a VB.NET program.  It is rather inevitable.

Comment: To each their own I suppose.